# Is there a keyboard shortcut for enabling dictation on iPad?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, voice-dictation, ipados, beta

I‘m using an iPad Pro 10.5 iPadOS 13.5 and a Slim Combo keyboard case. I use dictation a lot. Is there a keyboard shortcut for that?
Right now I have to toggle the default on-screen keyboard and touch the microphone key, but I would rather do it with an actual physical keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.  You'll need to [edit] your question to include the relevant info regarding version/build and hardware type.   Also, be sure you've opened a Feedback to Apple about this issue

Comment: Andreas - want to adopt my screen shot or point your question here that addresses shipping iPadOS? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390796/can-the-ipad-magic-keyboard-start-dictation-with-a-key-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also love to have this.

However, as of right now there is no keyboard shortcut to directly start dictation on the iPad.

Currently, the most convenient way, as you said, is to press and hold the downward facing arrow on the bottom right until the virtual keyboard pops up and then press on the dictation button.

Answer (score 8):

Apple added new shortcut in the recently release. Just press ctrl twice.

Comment: I would mark this as the updated correct answer. If I could. Perfect! (Many thanks).

Comment: This is correct and awesome. But where was it announced and is it configurable? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. "Dictation Shortcut" somewhere in Settings.